# Swift 3 how to scale image on hidden frame

Tags: swift3, uiimageview

I have photo inside the circle like this:

[Good circle. Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2zau.png)

And when i retrive the image from database it looks like this:

[Bad circle. image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjqsO.png)

I just resized the image when i uploaded to database.

What i want is to show full image inside the circle like scale the image to be looking like a circle.

Here some codes i use:

I use this code to resize the image before uploading to database.

```
// Resize image
func resized(withPercentage percentage: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
    let canvasSize = CGSize(width: size.width * percentage, height: size.height * percentage)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(canvasSize, false, scale)
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
    draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: canvasSize))
    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
}
func resized(toWidth width: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
    let canvasSize = CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat(ceil(width/size.width * size.height)))
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(canvasSize, false, scale)
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
    draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: canvasSize))
    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
}
```

I use this code to make image circle

```
func setRounded() {
    let radius = self.frame.width / 2
    self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

This code to resize the image before uploading to database:

```
 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {



        let myThumb2 = image.resized(toWidth: 300)
       //image.resized(toHeight: 300) how to set this height?


        self.profilepic.image = myThumb2
```

Comment: OK - you are explicitly drawing the image into the middle of the frame. I'll edit my answer to see if we can fix it...

Comment: @DonMag I've edited the question, I added the code which is resizing the image before uploading to database, but i didn't get how to use the Height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it looks like you're set to `Aspect Fit` - which give it the "letterbox" effect (blank space on top and bottom).

Edit: to fix your drawing issue, you can add a "resized to height" func...

```
// Resize image
func resized(toHeight height: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
    let canvasSize = CGSize(width: size.width * height / size.height, height: height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(canvasSize, false, scale)
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
    draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: canvasSize))
    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
}
```

and, since your "target" image frame is square, choose whether to call `toWidth` or `toHeight`:

```
// init, but will be replaced below
var finalImage: UIImage = UIImage()

var finalImageSize: CGFloat = 200.0

var w = myImg.size.width
var h = myImg.size.height

if w > h {
    finalImage = myImg.resized(toHeight: finalImageSize)!
} else {
    finalImage = myImg.resized(toWidth: finalImageSize)!
}
```

Make sure your destination UIImageView is also set to:

```
imgView.contentMode = .center
imgView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Once you see what's happening, I'm sure you can condense it down (create a `resized(toFit:)` function, for example) and add any necessary error checking :)

**Another Edit:** ... ***Second Option***

Of course, after all that, you are doing much of what UIImageView can do for you. For example:

```
// car.png is 750x400 pixels
let newImage = UIImage(named: "car.png")
let newImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
newImageView.image = newImage
newImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
newImageView.layer.cornerRadius = newImageView.frame.width / 2
newImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: When i set background to red i got same your photo, But when i set normal image i got a good circle like first photo but when i retrive image from database i got bad circle, I've tried aspect fit and fill, still the same!

Comment: Show either the code that is creating that view, or images of the layers. Can't help you any more by looking at just the output.

Comment: I've added the codes I used, check the question please.

Comment: Thank you so much for that work, but i didn't know how to use the second code which starts with "Var finalImageSize: " And there's error with "finalImage" the debug wants to change to "finalImageSize"

Comment: You only posted a little bit of your code, so I made some assumptions / guesses... `finalImageSize` estimates your "target" image frame to be 200x200; `finalImage` should previously be declared as a `UIImage`; ***However*** unless you have a particular reason, I'd suggest going with the second option and let `UIImageView` do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your UIImageView is bigger than the view it is in.

To solve this you can either resize the UIImageView to fit the view or set clipToBounds to false on the view containing the UIImageView.

Quick edit: If your image is already rounded and it is not the UIImageView that is rounded(Can't tell from the screenshots) this problem could be fixed by changing the Content Mode of the UIImageView to Aspect Fit

Comment: I've tried Aspect Fit and Fill None works, the normal image it looks good but the image retrived from database looks bad